# Custom Permission is not working to hide/unhide Lightning quick action on Lightning Record Page

Tags: permissions, administration, permission-sets, custom-permission

I need to Hide/Unhide Quick Action button on the Lightning record page based on the permission set.

Steps that I followed:

1. Created a Custom Permission and permission set and added the custom permission to
   the permission set.
2. Added the  'Set Action Visibility' filter to the action on the lightning record page.
   (Permission-->Custom Permission-->xxx = true.
3. Assigned the permission set to my user(sys admin).

If I login, the action is visible to me but when I login as business user still the action is visible. Neither the custom permission nor the permission set is assigned to the business user.

If I login as another sys admin user who don't have the permission set assigned, the action is not visible for them.

But not understand why the action is visible for all the business profile users. None of them have that permission set or custom permission.

Comment: Can you confirm if the same lightning page is assigned to the business user as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the custom permission or permission set is not added to business user and they were able to see this action which means there is high chance that there may be another lightning record page assigned to the business user.

You can check this from **View Page Assignment**  from lightning Record pages and make the same change there as well.